# appharbor sqlserver setup help - creating a database gets permission denied in database master

Tags: appharbor

I am trying to set up my sql server database on harbor. I added Shared Microsoft SQL Server as a service. I connected to the db using ms sql server management studio.

Whenever i am trying to create a database locally I get permission denied in database master.

I tried to search on your Appharbor site and stackoverflow for answers but I am stuck.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create new databases other that the one you start with. If you've deleted that, please remove and re-add the add-on.